# Extra window popping up when a button with two commands is fired

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter

```
from tkinter import *
# global new_width
# global new_height
# global new_rectangles
rectangle_values=[]
x = 0
y = 0
k = 0

def open_window():
    global k
    top=Toplevel()
    top.title("Rectangles")
    top.geometry("300x600")

    for i in range(0,int(rectangles.get())*2):
        if(i % 2) == 0:
            l4=Label(top, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i,column=0)
        rectangle_values.append(StringVar())
        en=Entry(top, textvariable=rectangle_values[i])
        en.grid(row=i,column=1)


    b3=Button(top, text="Save", width=12, command=save_content)
    b3.grid(row=int(rectangles.get())*2+1,column=0)
    b4=Button(top, text="Close", width=12, command=top.destroy)
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles.get())*2+1,column=1)
    k = int(rectangles.get())

def save_sheetsize():
    global x
    global y
    x = float(e2.get())
    y = float(e1.get())

temp_recta=[]
def save_content():   
    for j in range(0,int(rectangles.get())*2):
            temp_recta.append(rectangle_values[j].get())

window=Tk()

l3=Label(window, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0,column=0)

# defining entries
rectangles=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0,column=1)

# Defining buttons
b1=Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=lambda:(window.destroy(),open_window()))
b1.grid(row=3,column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.geometry("300x600")
window.mainloop()

root=Tk()

l1=Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Height]:")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Width]:")
l2.grid(row=1,column=0)

# defining entries
height=StringVar()
e1=Entry(root, textvariable=height)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

width=StringVar()
e2=Entry(root, textvariable=width)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)

b5=Button(root, text="Save", width=12, command=save_sheetsize)
b5.grid(row=2,column=0)
b6=Button(root, text="Close", width=12, command=root.destroy)
b6.grid(row=2,column=1)

root.title("Sheet Size")
root.geometry("300x600")
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I input a number at first and press the button which calls the function open_window and destroy, a window named tk pops up along with the window which is in open_window. When I close that tk window, the other window that I want also closes. I couldn't figure it out. How do I avoid that tk window from popping up?

Comment: Sorry I've provided a wrong information. It wouldn't `deiconify()`. It would be `iconify()` or `withdraw()`. I apologize.

Comment: Can you please show me where do I use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example you can follow to fix your problem, and modify, update as you need.

```
from tkinter import *
# global new_width
# global new_height
# global new_rectangles

temp_recta = []

def save_content(top):
    top.destroy()
    for j in range(0, int(rectangles.get()) * 2):
        temp_recta.append(rectangle_values[j].get())

    root = Toplevel()

    l1 = Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Height]:")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    l2 = Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Width]:")
    l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    # defining entries
    height = StringVar()
    e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=height)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    width = StringVar()
    e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=width)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    b5 = Button(root, text="Save", width=12, command=lambda: save_sheetsize(e1, e2, root))
    b5.grid(row=2, column=0)
    b6 = Button(root, text="Close", width=12, command=lambda: (root.destroy(), window.deiconify()))
    b6.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.title("Sheet Size")

def save_sheetsize(e1, e2, root):
    global x
    global y
    x = float(e2.get())
    y = float(e1.get())
    root.destroy()
    window.deiconify()

rectangle_values = []
x = 0
y = 0
k = 0

def open_window():
    window.withdraw()
    global k
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Rectangles")
    top.geometry("300x600")

    for i in range(0, int(rectangles.get()) * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(top, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        rectangle_values.append(StringVar())
        en = Entry(top, textvariable=rectangle_values[i])
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)

    b3 = Button(top, text="Save", width=12, command=lambda: save_content(top))
    b3.grid(row=int(rectangles.get()) * 2 + 1, column=0)
    b4 = Button(top, text="Close", width=12, command=lambda: (top.destroy(), window.deiconify()))
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles.get()) * 2 + 1, column=1)
    k = int(rectangles.get())

window = Tk()

l3 = Label(window, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0, column=0)

# defining entries
rectangles = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Defining buttons
b1 = Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=open_window)
b1.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.geometry("300x600")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked well but the first window pops up again at last.

Comment: Yes that's how I coded it. You can destroy that at the end if you want to. Just try to understand what is happening in this code and you will be able to do stuffs you want.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much.